# python compare words

Tags: python-3.x

I have stuck with following problem:
I am trying to get subject and compare from email (it's saved on disk, email in UTF-8)

```
import re

def check_subj():
    subj = ""
    file = open("/home/hikaru/Desktop/sub.eml", "r")

    for line in file:
        try:
            a = re.search("Subject:\ ", line, re.IGNORECASE)
            a = line[a.end():]
            subj = a
            break
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    return subj

print(check_subj())

if check_subj() == 'sub':
    print("yay")
```

Everything seems fine to me, "print" successfully shows me "sub", but comparison won't print "yay" for me.
I can't understand why -(

Comment: try `print(repr(check_subj()))`, I'd bet it's got a carriage return at the end or something.

Comment: Will need to see text of the .eml. I ran your code on a test email of mine in MIME and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Yup, it is really "\n", thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An end of line, as suggested, is the probable cause of your problem. Here is a more robust solution (the loop only)

```
for line in file:
   match = re.search("Subject:\ (.*)", line, re.IGNORECASE)
   if match:
      subj = match.group(1)
      break
```